# Change state of passed prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Im facing problem when I have component Header and inside Header I'm passing props to Navbar, but right now I need to change state of prop from Header inside Navbar. Inside Navbar I need somehow access menuState and be able to change state, which I need to pass into styled-components.

**HEADER:**

```
        <HeaderWrapper>
            <HeaderLogo>
                <Link to={"/"}>
                    <img src={''} height="45" alt=""/>
                </Link>
            </HeaderLogo>
                {isDesktop &&
                <HeaderRight>
                    <HeaderJoinUs to="/join-us">join us</HeaderJoinUs>
                    <ButtonExtend as={Button} color={"#FFF"}><Link to={"/contact-us"}>Let's talk</Link></ButtonExtend>
                    <SocialsExtend color={"#000"} as={Socials}/>
                    <HeaderBurgerContainer onClick={() => setMenuState(!menuState)}>
                        <HeaderBurger>
                            <HeaderBurgerInner menuState={menuState}/>
                        </HeaderBurger>
                    </HeaderBurgerContainer>
                </HeaderRight>
            <Navbar menuState={menuState}/>
        </HeaderWrapper>
```

**NAVBAR:**

```
   const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

       <Nav>
            {navLinks.map(i =>{
                return (  
                    <NavItem key={i.path} onClick={() => setOpen(props.menuState)}>
                        <StyledNavLink exact={i.exact} to={i.path} activeClassName={'CdTfP'}>
                            <span data-link={i.content.en}></span>
                            {i.content.en}
                        </StyledNavLink>
                    </NavItem>
                )
            })}
        </Nav>
```

Comment: Just pass `setMenuState` as a prop to `Navbar` and call it.

Comment: @BrianThompson Could you please send me some example how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: There's not much to it, just pass the function just like you did `menuState`. Wherever you need to update the `Header` state, just call the function. Its a pretty fundamental pattern in React. Read [here about Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a function in your `header` component which can change your `menuState` and pass this function with `menuState` together into `Navbar` component and when you need to change the `menuState` just call this `function`; for example like this:

```
function Header(){
  const [menuState, setMenuState] = useState();

  return (
  <HeaderWrapper>
    <HeaderLogo>
        <Link to={"/"}>
            <img src={''} height="45" alt=""/>
        </Link>
    </HeaderLogo>
        {isDesktop &&
        <HeaderRight>
            <HeaderJoinUs to="/join-us">join us</HeaderJoinUs>
            <ButtonExtend as={Button} color={"#FFF"}><Link to={"/contact-us"}>Let's talk</Link></ButtonExtend>
            <SocialsExtend color={"#000"} as={Socials}/>
            <HeaderBurgerContainer onClick={() => setMenuState(!menuState)}>
                <HeaderBurger>
                    <HeaderBurgerInner menuState={menuState}/>
                </HeaderBurger>
            </HeaderBurgerContainer>
        </HeaderRight>
    <Navbar setMenuState={setMenuState} menuState={menuState}/>
  </HeaderWrapper>
  )
}
```

and in your `Navbar` just pass the `value` you want to set as `menuState` value to `props.setMenuState` function

Comment: Just added like you said, but state isnt changing. I got onClick event like this: onClick={() => props.setMenuState(props.menuState)}

Comment: why are you setting `menuState` to its value again?

Comment: I got burger menu which open me navbar and inside this navbar I need to change the same state when user clicks on link.

Comment: I know what you are trying to do but you are setting the `menuState` value to itself again and it's not a new `value`

Comment: glad it's helped ;)